# Placing contents of form and map side by side with HTML5

Tags: css, responsive-design

I want to put the contents of map and form side by side. I want the code to have responsive design. I have tried putting contents in table and list format. But still form is on top of map. I want to have contents side by side when it is displayed on a wider screen. While on smaller width screens have them on one over the other.

Please can anyone suggest best way to achieve this?

Comment: Use media queries to detect the size of screen and give your CSS accordingly say 50% for map and form in bigger screen sizes and 100% in smaller screen sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's pretty simple with medias queries ...

HTML

```
<div id="map"> <!-- your map --> </div>
<div id="form"> <!-- your form --> </div>
```

CSS

```
#map, #form {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

@media handheld, only screen and (max-width: 500px), only screen and (max-device-width: 500px) {
    #map, #form {
        width: auto;
        float: none;
    }
}
```

Replace 500px with your breaking point when you don't want DIV side by side anymore.